# Execute batch files in MS-Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, vifm

I use [VIFM](https://vifm.info/) from MS-Windows. How do I execute batch (**.bat**) files from VIFM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First select the batch file and then run `!%"c`. You may want to append the following :

- `%m` to show the execution output in a popup window.
- `%i` to ignore the execution output.
- `&` the put the process in the background; if you are running a GUI program or a long running job.